# Access to Google Nexus 4 Secure Element (SE)

Tags: nfc

I’m working on technical part of a project for big bank and looking for information about using Secure Element (SE) that is embedded into Google Nexus 4. 
What is a process to get access to SE?
I mean how to initiate a process with Google.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to contact them directly, but Google will not give you access to (embedded) SE: they don't want competitors on their wallet application (specially on Android systems).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It will be nice to get official answer from Google.
I'm wondering what is official way to contact them on this matter.
May Samsung be a way to go with this kind of request for Samsung Galaxy S III.

Comment: I've already contacted them and that was the 'official answer'.

Comment: As you can see on a statement at the last Google IO they are not planning to give access to the secure element. http://youtu.be/HkzPc8ZvCco?t=58m11s

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, current android version(4.0.4) has enabled access to SE without having support of platform vendor.
Please refere
http://nelenkov.blogspot.sg/2012/08/accessing-embedded-secure-element-in.html

Comment: With this approach you can only gain access to the Applets on the SE, you cannot load your own applets to the SE. To do this, you will need the vendor keys for the SE.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your ambition is, can you elaborate ? Loading an application of your own onto the secure element will require crypto keys that only Google can provide, and they probably never will, for many reasons.
Alternatively, you should be able to do the same with a SIM. It only takes a few tools to load and configure an application on a test SIM (with test SIM), then you can fit it into a phone and access it through the Open Mobile API (see the [SEEK for Android](http://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/) open source project) which is available on many devices.