# How do the big companies implement Card Emulation?

Tags: android, nfc

I'm writing a school paper on NFC boarding and have a question regarding the NFC operating modes. I've been looking at some whitepapers (http://www.nfc-forum.org/resources/white_papers/NFC_in_Public_Transport.pdf, http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/stb/fast-travel/Documents/iata-public-whitepaper-issue1.pdf) and they all seem to advocate the use of card emulation, but how would they go about developing for example an Android app which uses card emulation when there is no support for card emulation in the Android SDK? Do they contact Google to gain access to some non-public API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commercial agreement with Google and/or Telco.

Card emulation implies access to Secure Element (SIM Based or Embedded on mobile), but  Google does not allow to access the Embedded one (by hiding the related API) and the same is for Telco for the SIM Based (Telco are the owner of the SIM). I think they want all the 'pie'.
You may have a loook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450182/access-to-google-nexus-4-secure-element-se/13451297#13451297).

Comment: So if one of the airlines would like to create an application as described in the second link, they would not be able to use card emulation unless they could strike a deal with Google or Telco?

Comment: That's right. I've the same problem. You may explore MicroSD NFC enabled with SE embedded on it, but it seems they've some problems related to data transmission (the antenna is too small, position of the MicroSD under metal cover or battery, etc...)

Comment: Don't explore MicroSD NFC it's a dead end because no phone I know of has the SWP pin on the MicroSD connected to the NFC chip. Without the connection the MicroSD is as dumb as an NFC sticker that you can put on your phone.